# Convert letter to lowercase letter automatically on keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to convert letters automatically on keypress, tried this

```js
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  $("#nick").val().toLowerCase();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id=nick value="">
```

But when I write Uppercase letters, it doesnt convert to lowercase. Where I did mistake ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't modifying the existing value. You need to re-assign the lowercase value:

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
  var value = $("#nick").val().toLowerCase();

  $("#nick").val(value);
});
```

---

Since the `keypress` event won't change the last character, I would suggest listening to the [`input` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/input) instead. The `keyup` event would work as well.

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/0q4g69da/)

```
$(document).on('input', function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
});
```

Without jQuery:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/3bbr5egj/)

```
document.addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  e.target.value = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
});
```

Comment: Works like a charm, listening input would be the better approach for that. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

you gotta use the converted text somewhere, right? :)

```
$(document).on('keypress', function(e) {
    $("#nick").val($("#nick").val().toLowerCase());
});
```

**UPDATE**

if you use `keyup` it'll work as desired: **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/k1xm028q/)**

```
$(document).on('keyup', function(e) {
    $("#nick").val($("#nick").val().toLowerCase());
});
```

Comment: Works, but if the last letter is uppercase, it doesnt fix it. What do you suggest ?

Comment: let me check and get to you

Comment: @user198989 See my answer. Listen the to `input` event instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use below approach.

```
$(document).on('keyup','#nick',function(e){
    $(this).val(e.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase());
})
```

```js
$(document).on('keyup','#nick',function(e){
    $(this).val(e.currentTarget.value.toLowerCase());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="nick" value="">
```